# Как в Typescript сделать тип данных -- строка определенной длины

Tags: typescript

Нужно сделать тип данных в Typescript, который будет строкой длиной 13 или 15 символов и никакой другой !

Попробовал поискать в интернете возможные варианты, но к видимому результату не пришел (((

Comment: Любая строка длиной в 13/15 символов или есть список cлов?

Comment: Чисто типами по-моему не сделать

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59383265/4928642

Comment: Можно так, если вам охота этим заняться https://stackoverflow.com/a/66212954/13349770

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
type IsThirteen<T extends number> = 13 extends T ? true : never
type IsFifteen<T extends number> = 15 extends T ? true : never

type LengthOfString<S extends string, T extends string[] = []> = S extends `${string}${infer R}`
  ? LengthOfString<R, [...T, string]>
  : T['length'];

type IsLengthThirteenOrFifteen<T extends string> = true extends IsThirteen<LengthOfString<T>>
    ? T
    : true extends IsFifteen<LengthOfString<T>>
        ? T
        : never

function IsLengthThirteenOrFifteenGuard <T extends string>(a: IsLengthThirteenOrFifteen<T>) {
  return a;
}

const b = IsLengthThirteenOrFifteenGuard('1131111111111')
```

Источники:

- [StringOfLength](https://github.com/doox911-opensource/typescript/blob/main/type-challenges/medium/Length_of_String.md)
- [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgFQBYEsBOwIQHYB4FQQAem2AJnFNgK4C2ARhGgHxQC8UAjAMyEk4UoBAPxRgaatABcVCADcmAWABQoSLDgAxFADNMOfH1KCaDJqw6cArEYGURYidNkK0KlWugAZHAHNgSADyOgDK4ijYvrghtuSUcOGRADRCsYIJaBG%20ANoAuuxQeRZQMcTGlAAGACQA3hlZAL61ETpMUABKDRUqUFCiPpEBwWGZkbjtKdkAdDMIKfWRucw9UDII2QDkADZ%20ARu5ANzuquDQ8AP%20SMjo%20tiBaNp6WHgEZXZQC77F4pJplPDXDDPXAXIahRJRBDMZbKXq9UQIFa9GQ-aBvOIaR63EG7ILg0aQ6FIuHwoTEkkybDyJTKFQ6ajYADGwBQAHtsBpQVdUECcPcsc8AOLUACGaDIUEM6PSEOYAAoRTJzrjAbd%20bpsVCAJRQGorNAQYDUNAckVHZQNY6M9kJKD0ArKwbcm7PdVPHDCsVkOUbTgAJm4ABYrAA2ADsAA4AJycAAMnE4Gy1QA)